# How write python to Read the first two lines from a text file named "file1.txt" Write the two lines read from "file1.txt" to a new file "file2.txt"

Tags: python, new-operator, file-handling, readlines, console.writeline

Read the first two lines from a text file named "file1.txt" Write the two lines read from "file1.txt" to a new file "file2.txt"

Answer (score 1):

```
a_file = open("file1.txt", "r")
number_of_lines = 2
with open("file2.txt", "w") as new_file:
    for i in range(number_of_lines):
        line = a_file.readline()
        new_file.write(line)
a_file.close()
```

I'm sure there is a neater solution out there somewhere but this will work!
Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Write a Python program to

1. Read the first two lines from a text file named "file1.txt"
2. Write the two lines read from "file1.txt" to a new file called
   "file2.txt"
3. Read "file2.txt" and Print the contents

```py
fhandle1 = open("file1.txt","r")
fhandle2 = open("file2.txt","w")

str = fhandle1.readline()
fhandle2.write(str)
str = fhandle1.readline()
fhandle2.write(str)

fhandle1.close()
fhandle2.close()

fhandle3 = open("file2.txt")
print(fhandle3.read())
fhandle3.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2 lines:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as r:
    with open("file2.txt", "w") as w:
        w.write(r.readline() + r.readline())
```

Each time `r.readline()` is called, it goes to the next line. So if you wanted to read `n` lines; use:

Note that `.readline() + r.readline()` is only 2 seperate lines if there is a new line (`\n`) at the end of the first line

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as r:
    with open("file2.txt", "w") as w:
        # Change 2 to number of lines to read
        for i in range(2):
            w.write(r.readline())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f1=open("file1.txt","r")
f2=open("file2.txt","w")
fcontent=f1.readline()
f2.write(fcontent)
fcontent=f1.readline()
f2.write(fcontent)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 f1 = open("file1.txt","r")

    f2 = open("file2.txt","w")

    str = f1.readline()
    f2.write(str)
    str = f1.readline()
    f2.write(str)
    
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    
    f3 = open("file2.txt")
    print(f3.read())
    f3.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
fhandle1 = open("file1.txt")
fhandle2 = open("file2.txt","w")
fcontents = fhandle1.readline()
fhandle2.write(fcontents)
fcontents = fhandle1.readline()
fhandle2.write(fcontents)
fhandle1.close()
fhandle2.close()

fhandle3 = open("file2.txt")
print(fhandle3.read())
fhandle3.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
fhandle1 = open("file1.txt","r")

l1 = fhandle1.readline()
l2 = fhandle1.readline()

fhandle2 = open("file2.txt","w")

fhandle2.write(l1)
fhandle2.write(l2)

fhandle2 = open("file2.txt")
print(fhandle2.read())
fhandle2.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).